# How to get current version of registry resource in wso2esb custom mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm creating a custom mediator for wso2 esb and in this mediator I'm reading the configuration from registry. To be exact: gov:conf/mediator.conf

Now to read this configuration I'm using MessageContext.getFormat("") and it works well but seems to be caching the resource. So if I change something in the configuration I have to restart the server (esb) for the changes to be in effect.

Is there any other way to read the resource without getting an old cached version?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps, but the esb caches the registry for better performance. More information can be found here.

[WSO2 Registry](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Working+with+the+Registry)

Maybe if you change the cachableDuration parameter it might work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to impact the performance of esb. There are many other services deployed on the server. I just want the same behaviour like for the send mediator which can use the endpoints stored in the registry. Send mediator seems to always get the current version and no restarts or waits are required after changing endpoints xml...

Comment: Sorry, then I cannot assist you furthermore. Have you checked if that changes anything? If I remember right, the default caching of the registry is 15 minutes.